# How to install openconnect-sso on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: software-installation, vpn, openconnect

I would like to install [openconnect-ssh](https://github.com/vlaci/openconnect-sso). The install instructions from the project seem complex, I'm not sure what `pipx` is.

How do I install openconnect-sso on Ubuntu without using pipx and using native Ubuntu qt libraries?

I tried to install it using `pip`, but I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/bin/openconnect-sso", line 5, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.cli import main
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso import app, config, __version__
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.authenticator import Authenticator, AuthResponseError
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/authenticator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.saml_authenticator import authenticate_in_browser
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/saml_authenticator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.browser import Browser
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .browser import Browser, DisplayMode, Terminated
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/browser.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import webengine_process as web
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/webengine_process.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/bin/openconnect-sso", line 5, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.cli import main
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso import app, config, __version__
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.authenticator import Authenticator, AuthResponseError
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/authenticator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.saml_authenticator import authenticate_in_browser
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/saml_authenticator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openconnect_sso.browser import Browser
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .browser import Browser, DisplayMode, Terminated
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/browser.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import webengine_process as web
  File "/home/merlijn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openconnect_sso/browser/webengine_process.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineScript, QWebEngineProfile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to install the Qt5 Python dependencies:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine vpnc-scripts openconnect
```

Then you install openconnect-sso using pip

```shell
pip install openconnect-sso
```

Afterwards, you can easily run the app:

```
$ openconnect-sso -s vpn.example.com --browser-display-mode shown
[info     ] Authenticating to VPN endpoint [openconnect_sso.app] address=vpn.example.com name=
[info     ] Response received              [openconnect_sso.authenticator] id=main message=Please complete the authentication process in the AnyConnect Login window. title=Login
[info     ] Browser started                [webengine] startup_info=StartupInfo(url='https://vpn.example.com/...', credentials=None)
[info     ] Loading page                   [webengine] url=https://vpn.example.com/...
[info     ] Terminate requested.           [webengine] 
[info     ] Exiting browser                [webengine] 
[info     ] Browser exited                 [openconnect_sso.browser.browser] 
[info     ] Response received              [openconnect_sso.authenticator] id=success message=
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an issue I opened linking to my installation instructions: https://github.com/vlaci/openconnect-sso/issues/114 <-- (upvote this with a thumbs up sign on GitHub if you agree and want to get it attention)

...which are here: **[How to use "openconnect" (via the `openconnect-sso` wrapper) with SAML and Duo two-factor authentication via Okta Single-Sign-on (SSO)](https://superuser.com/a/1753172/425838)** <-- see here for full instructions, details, and screenshots.

In short, **do this to install `openconnect` and `openconnect-sso` on Linux Ubuntu:**

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vpnc-scripts openconnect   # install openconnect
sudo apt install python3

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install openconnect-sso      # install openconnect-sso

# install openconnect-sso dependencies, including forcing a reinstall of PyQt5

# uninstall
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQt5
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
python3 -m pip uninstall keyring

# reinstall
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
python3 -m pip install PyQt5-sip
python3 -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
python3 -m pip install keyring

python3 -m pip install cffi

# Check the version
# My output is: `openconnect-sso 0.7.3`
openconnect-sso --version
```

**Usage** (note: for how to find your server address and SAML group, see ["How to find your VPN server address and SAML group" at the bottom of my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1753172/425838)):

```bash
VPN_SERVER_ADDRESS="myvpn.whatever.com"   # example server address to connect to
VPN_SAML_GROUP="whatever-saml-whatever"   # example SAML group name
VPN_USER="my.username@something.com"      # example username
# or perhaps just this for the username:
# VPN_USER="my.username"

# connect via `openconnect-sso`
# The first time ever, you must specify everything
openconnect-sso --server "${VPN_SERVER_ADDRESS}/${VPN_SAML_GROUP}" --user "${VPN_USER}"
# Subsequent connection attempts can be done with just this, since apparently
# the server address, SAML group, and username are cached after the first usage
openconnect-sso
```